# MongoDB updateOne with upsert:true keeps inserting new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a *lastTracks* collection which I intend to keep it updated with new track data.
I try to do that using this piece of code with MongoDB driver for NodeJS:

```
db.collection('lastTracks').updateOne(
  {
    'track.deviceID': lastPacket.deviceID,
    timestampZero: {$lte: lastPacket.timestamp}
  },
  {
    $set: {          
      timestampZero: lastPacket.timestamp,          
    },
    $setOnInsert: {'track.deviceID': lastPacket.deviceID}
  },
  { upsert: true}
);
```

What I want to do is to perform an update for timestampZero if there is a document for deviceID in collection and it's timestampZero is lower or equal than packet's timestamp; And if there is no such document, then insert it.

The problem is whenever this piece of code runs, a new document gets inserted and no update operation happens on existing document with given deviceID. And even if I create an index for 'track.deviceID' a duplicate key error happens.

UPDATE:
I found that the reason a new document gets inserted every time is because there is a document with same deviceID but greater timestamp in the collection, and so my update condition evaluates to false and then Mongo tries to insert a new document (as I wanted with upsert:true).
But what I want is that if timestamp is greater than lastPacket.timestamp neither update nor insert happen.
With a little search I found that my solution could be simply creating a unique index on 'tracks.deviceID' and then ignoring the duplicate error: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels
or I can do a two phase commit: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

The first solution works simple and well but just doesn't feel right and the second solution is a little complicated both for understanding and implementation, so my question is **is there any better way for this?**

Comment: What does find return for the query you're trying? I suspect that timestampZero: $lte: lastPacket.timestamp  is never true.

Comment: how can the current and updated `track.deviceID` be same `'track.deviceID': lastPacket.deviceID` ??

Comment: @wrangler When a document's 'track.deviceID' matches the lastPacket,deviceID there is no need to update it's deviceID, but I added that part just for the situations that document doesn't exists and so the newly inserted document must have 'tack.deviceID'

Comment: @wrangler I updated my code and used $setOnInsert instead.

Comment: @user602525 You are right. I fixed my question.